# Filling webform with selenium, how to click button that is only enabled for certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automatically fill in the form in this website using selenium with python:
https://breast.predict.nhs.uk/tool
I can fill in all the boxes except the "micrometastases only". If I try to click this one in the way I've filled in the others, i.e.:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/button[1]")
elem.click()
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[3]
/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/button[1]"}
```

I believe this is because the micrometastases button only becomes available if/when positive nodes = 1.

In order to try to fix this, I looked at using explicit waiting, in the following way:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/button[1]")))
element.click()
```

This outputs the following error:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

What would be the right way to click this button? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, the button only becomes enabled after filling in the previous value and clicking somewhere else on the website. After changing that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath` option.

```
driver.get("https://breast.predict.nhs.uk/tool")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"nodes"))).send_keys('1')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-default btn-sm custom' and text()='Yes']"))).click()
```